# How can I convert this to return multiple items?

Tags: c#, list, random

I have a list of games, which I need to select randomly, by the day of week,
the following code works perfectly for 1 game.

```
   var gameOfTheDay = games.AllActive[(int)(DateTime.Today.GetHashCode()) % games.AllActive.Count()];
```

What I need is to return more then 1 game, randomized, based on X ( X in the case above is the day of the week, I will change it to a specific string )

I need this to create a semi-random generation of items.

Semi - since I want to feed it a keyword, and get the same results Per keyword

Random - since I need to make the game list random

For example, every time you enter Page with title "hello", you will see THE SAME games, that were selected specificly for that keyword from the games list based on the keyword "hello".

In the same way the gameOfTheDay Works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LINQ for this:

```
int limit = 10;
string keyword = "foo";

Random rng = new Random(keyword.GetHashCode());
var gamesOfTheDay = games.OrderBy(x => rng.Next()).Take(limit);
```

However, this will have some overhead for the sort.  If you have a lot of games compared to the amount you're selecting—enough that the sort might be too expensive, and enough that it's safe to just keep retrying in the event of a collision—manually doing it might be faster:

```
HashSet<Game> gamesOfTheDay = new HashSet<Game>();

while(gamesOfTheDay.Count < limit && gamesOfTheDay.Count < games.Length)
{
    int idx = rng.Next(games.Length);
    gamesOfTheDay.Add(games[idx]);
}
```

Note that in either case the `Random` is constructed with a seed dependent on the keyword, so the order will be the same every time for that keyword.  You could similarly combine the hashes of the current DateTime and the keyword to get a unique random sequence for that day-keyword combination.

Comment: Sorry, i am not interested in getting random games and sort them i know to do that by myself.
Please look at edited question for more details.

Comment: I updated my answer to seed the RNG with the hash of the keyword.  Is that what you wanted?

Answer (score 1):

Use similar code to what you have now to randomly add games to a list of games (which will initially be empty) - if the game is already in the list, don't add it.

Stop when the list is the right size.

Untested code:

```
var rand = new Random();
var randomGames = new List<game>();
while(randomGames.Count < limit)
{
   var aGame = games.AllActive[rand.Next(limit)];
   if (!randomGames.Contains(aGame))
   {
      randomGames.Add(aGame);
   }
}
```

Comment: `aGame` should be the same game for all executions of the loop, as the index calculation will return the same value each time.

Comment: Anthony do you have any other idea?

Comment: @Dementic, @Anthony - quite right. Code amended to use `Random`.

Comment: @Dementic, a tried and true approach is to perform a shuffle and then select the whatever number of items you need in order. If you're interested in that, look up the Fisher Yates algorithm. To achieve your desire of using a keyword to get the same results, you can look into transforming that keyword into an appropriate seed for a random number generator.

Comment: @Dementic, the benefit of using a shuffle as opposed to random selection is that you eliminate collisions [selecting the same item], particularly if you're selecting a large percentage of the source list (the more items you select, the greater your chances of collision). On the other hand, if you're selecting a tiny percentage, then maybe you deal with the occasional collision, as Oded does in his answer.